# GIT merge file contents are incorrect for the file name. (SmartGit/Hg || IntelliJ IDEA) && (P4Merge || KDiff3)

Tags: git, intellij-idea, smartgit, kdiff3, p4merge

## THE PROBLEM

In setting up the merge tool to resolve conflicts, the files sent to the merge tool are not correct for the content they contain. I have tried searching Stack Overflow, but have not found an answer.

---

### Details

I'm new to GIT. In trying to learn more, I've set up a private repo on Bitbucket. I have Windows 7 64-bit and the following software:

- GIT Client: SmartGit/Hg
- Code Editor: IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate
- Merge: P4Merge || KDiff3

When KDiff3 is called from SmartGit/Hg:

> **(A)** C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\smartgit6393324384790956404tmp\compare_base_2787531226782357806_README.md
>   **(B)** C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\smartgit6393324384790956404tmp\compare_ours_2686269382530657828_README.md
>   **(C)** C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\smartgit6393324384790956404tmp\compare_theirs_8849401324186420794_README.md
>   **(OUTPUT)** D:\Path\to\project\README.md

When KDiff3 is called from IDEA:

> **(A)** C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\Merge_Result2324777776464644375.md
>   **(B)** C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\Local_Changes7034162268721107201.markdown
>   **(C)** C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\Changes_from_Server__revision_d7bcd6bd85df4f7bae648786dfa944825991b4f3_1371061438544389037.markdown
>   **(OUTPUT)** D:\Path\to\project\README.md

- (A) correctly displays the base, in the case of IDEA "Merge_Result" is confusing, but at least it has the base data.
- The contents of (B) is HEAD data where it should be LOCAL.
- The contents of (C) is displaying LOCAL data where it should be HEAD.
- (OUTPUT) is the correct location of conflicted file that the merge/resolution should be saved to.

My understanding is that local data is in mine/ours/yours/local files and the head data should be in theirs/remote/head files.

---

### Settings

SmartGit/Hg P4Merge settings:

> **File Pattern:** *.md
>   **Command:** P:\Program Files\Perforce\p4merge.exe
>   **Arguments:** ${baseFile} ${leftFile} ${rightFile} ${mergedFile}

SmartGit/Hg KDiff3 settings:

> **File Pattern:** *.md
>   **Command:** P:\Program Files (x86)\KDiff3\kdiff3.exe
>   **Arguments:** ${baseFile} ${leftFile} ${rightFile} -o ${mergedFile}

I'll update the file pattern once I resolve the problem.

IDEA KDiff3 settings:

> **Path to executable:** P:\Program Files (x86)\KDiff3\kdiff3.exe
>   **Parameters:** %2 %1 %3 -o %4

---

### The question

Both P4Merge and KDiff3 have the same problems, which makes me think something may be wrong with my local GIT install, but I have no idea where to look next to troubleshoot and resolve this. What have I done wrong and how can I fix it?

I'd like to get on with learning Git, but I can't focus on that if I am worried about the accuracy of my diff and merge tools (or the data they are working with.)

---

### References

P4Merge: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/P4MERGE.html
KDiff3: http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/doc/documentation.html

I have three more, but I don't have enough reputation to post more links. They amount to Bitbucket, Araxis documentation, and a Stack Overflow page that references undocumented options/arguments/parameters in P4Merge. I'm not using Araxis, but they have some good instructions on where to find your conflict resolver settings in a number of different programs.

---

### Creating the conflict

README.md (first version)

```
# This is my README  
This file has been modified BASE
```

Pull.

README.md (edited, committed, approved through Bitbucket/webpage)

```
# This is my README  
This file has been modified SERVER
```

README.md (modified locally)

```
# This is my README  
This file has been modified LOCAL
```

Stash changes. Pull. Apply Stash. Congratulations! You now have a conflict that needs to be resolved.

Comment: When double clicking your conflicting `README.md` in SmartGit, what will e.g. KDiff3 display? When removing the external conflict solver definition in SmartGit, what will SmartGit's internal Conflict Solver display? Please publish screenshot somewhere.

Comment: ![SmartGit/Hg](http://i1331.photobucket.com/albums/w584/npet/Stack%20Overflow/SmartGit_Hg_zps5b66dcb1.png~original)
![KDiff3](http://i1331.photobucket.com/albums/w584/npet/Stack%20Overflow/KDiff3_zpsd6418a0f.png~original)
I tried to add the images to my original post, but I do not have enough reputation to add more than 2 links or images.

Comment: Could it be that Git is rebasing, not merging? In this case, Git switched to the "server" branch and more or less cherry-picks your "local" changes. Hence, "local" and "server" will be swapped.

Comment: Both merge and rebase have the same result.